# How to run wordpress site on "mysitewp.com"?

Tags: domain, amazon

I have created one windows instance at amazon lightsail.There I have installed wordpress using IIS. Now I want to run my wordpress site on a the following name:
"mysite.com" . I have added this on wp_config.php file. But when I was trying it through browser it is providing the following error:

This site can’t be reached 
mysitewp.com’s server IP address could not be found.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

How can i solve it?

Comment: Have you registered the domain? Have you pointed it to your server?

Comment: no. i didn't register it. i was trying with internet information services[iis] server.

Comment: I have tried to host the wordpress website using IP. but is showing same. how can I access it through IP?

Comment: I don’t see what IIS has to do with trying to use a domain you don’t own?

Comment: If you want the site to run on a certain domain, you need to register that domain and point DNS to your server. If instead you just want this already-installed site to work from the IP address, it depends on how you set it up. If you set it up at that IP address, take the domain out of wp-config and clear your cache and it should just work. If you didn't set it up at that IP address, it's usually safest to use a database migration plugin to change the URL from the domain to the IP.

Comment: how can I set that IP address for my wordpress site if I want to access it through IP? Because when I am giving that IP on URL it is showing IIS server home page.